# How do I restart django server that is running in the background?

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu

I run `ssh ubuntu@myapp.com`, change to the django directory for my app and then run `ps | aux less`. I do not see any processes with python in the command. How do I restart my django server as it is running in the background?

Comment: the command is `ps aux | less`

Comment: how did you start the django server?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends how you're running the Django server. If you set the Django server to run with Apache, `sudo service apache2 restart` will do the trick.

If you're running the test server (`manage.py runserver`), you could use `fg` to bring the job into the foreground, and tinker with it, but the Django development server automatically detects changes for you (there's no need to restart).

Comment: If I'm running dev server in a container and there is unrecoverable error, like `ModuleNotFoundError` then the Django server would not auto reload and I have to do it manually, so I would like to have an option to restart it from cli instead of restarting the whole container.